# Completely destroy Bootstrap tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I need to completely destroy Bootstrap tabs. The original markup from [Bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs):

```
<div>

  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#messages" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#settings" aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">...</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">...</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="messages">...</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="settings">...</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Desired markup after complete destroy is something like this:

```
<div>

  <ul>
    <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#profile">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#messages">Messages</a></li>
    <li><a href="#settings">Settings</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div>
    <div class="active" id="home">...</div>
    <div id="profile">...</div>
    <div id="messages">...</div>
    <div id="settings">...</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

**So the goal is to remove all the Bootstrap classes, listeners, etc. Is there a function/method in Bootstrap 3 for that?**

Btw, please I am not looking for "solution" like `$.removeClass('.nav, .nav-tabs, .tab-pane','#bla');` & `$.removeAttr('role','#bla');` etc.

Comment: If you want to remove all the classes and just have your markup like you have it in the second code block, then just do that. If you want it to still function like bootstrap tabs, then you need the classes, or do your own css and js. I don't understand what this is a question about

Comment: There is a large code which is not mine. I need to get rid of Bootstrap Tab. That's the question about.

Comment: I'm pretty certain no such function exists.

Answer (score 0):

There is no JS function in Bootstrap 3 that does what you want. Checkout their docs http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/. Are you just trying to remove the attributes from the DOM with client-side JavaScript, or permanently change the HTML on the server?

Either way, it sounds like you will need to write some custom code to accomplish your goal, since it is not something commonly done.

Comment: I am trying to change the code on client-side of course.